# Git Merge: parallel identical additions are merged without conflict by including the same code block TWICE in the merged file without complaint. Why?

Tags: git, merge

I have a slightly tricky history in my Git log that I am trying to understand fully.

Before explaining the sequence of commits, let me paste images of the Git log (using SmartGit to visualize the history) for a file in question:

[image: git_history_later]

...

[image: git_history_earlier]

Shown is the Git history relevant to my question, with the irrelevant middle section snipped away.

Two developers made code changes to the file in question, Developer 1 and Developer 2.

**Developer 1**

- checks out the branch labeled '*origin/staging*' in the picture (but which was also '*origin/development*' at the time it was checked out)
- **adds a small code block** (see below)
- commits and pushes - this push is labeled '*jon-dev-test-merge*', above
- makes a simple whitespace change to the code from the previous commit, and commits/pushes this whitespace change, labeled '*jon-dev-test-merge-2*', above
- **realizes he should have been working on a separate branch**, so *starts over* and checks out '*origing/staging*' (at that time, '*origin/development*'), into a new branch called '*jons_dev*', which he pushes to, and sets up tracking for, on origin
- adds the same small code block (NOT including the whitespace change) to this new branch (blue line) (into a commit sometime before the one labeled '*test-merge-sales*')
- later, seeing that Developer 2 has made a change on the '*origin/development*' branch, merges '*origin/development*' into his '*jons_dev*' branch

**Meanwhile...**

**Developer 2**

- checks out the branch labeled '*origin/staging*' in the picture (but which was also '*origin/development*' at the time it was checked out)
- makes a code change to another file (completely unrelated to the code change from Developer 1, above) - this is in his working copy on his local development machine
- pulls Developer 1's code changes to the '*origin/development*' branch to his local machine and merges into a local-only branch/working copy; the merge succeeds without conflict.  Note that we don't see Developer 2's merge into his local branch (because he did not push that branch to the origin), but only the merge (see next bullet point) from his local branch back into what was the '*origin/development*' branch at that time.
- merges into the tracked development branch from origin on his local machine, and pushes the merge back up to origin - labeled '*vladimir-test-merge*', above

So far, so good.

Here is my question.

In the process of understanding the sequence of events above, I noticed something odd - no changes from the '*origin/development*' branch **for the file in question** needed to be incorporated into the merge labeled '*origin/development*' - whose explanation turned out to be that in this file, **the identical changes to this file, made in parallel, not including whitespace, were therefore present in both files** so that just the changes from the '*jons_dev*' branch were required (and this is how the merge was performed).

However, I noticed something from the merge, involving Git's method for merging and determining conflicts, that I cannot explain.

To demonstrate the issue in the simplest way for my question, I first created the test branches indicated in the screenshots - '*test-merge-sales*', and '*jon-dev-test-merge*' / '*jon-dev-test-merge-2*'.  I then checked out the branch '*test-merge-sales*' and performed two separate merges into this branch (cancelling the merge in between the two tests).

The relevant results from these two merges are shown below.  (Addendum: due to comments below the question, the second merge scenario is easily explained.  However, the FIRST merge scenario is still a question.)

---

**(0) BASE file**

Before showing a 3-way screenshot from the two merges, here is a screenshot of the relevant section of the file **as it existed in the '*origin/staging*' branch BEFORE the branches diverged**:

**The base file:**
[image: pre-branch-file]

The image shows how the file looked for BOTH developers, BEFORE any changes were made by either developer.

There are also comments present, which explain exactly what code changes were made by each developer to arrive at the pre-merge state shown in Case (1), below.

As you can see from the comments, Developer 1 adds a function - `print_customer_part_order_history`, followed by a second function, `print_sales_analysis_page`, to a given spot in the file.  In parallel, the other branch has added to it a single function - `print_customer_part_order_history` - in exactly the same place in the file.  The code is identical, including whitespace.

This is the state of the file moving into Merge Case (1), below.

---

**(1) Merge from '*jon-dev-test-merge*' into the '*test-merge-sales*' branch**

*Note: This merge scenario is my main question.  Due to comments below the question, the question associated with the other merge scenario (#2, below) is already answered.*

This merge **did not result in a conflict**.  Opening a diff viewer for the merged file, here is a screenshot from the relevant (merged) lines:

[image: merge_from_jon-dev-test-merge]

(Click this [link to full-size image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kwlj5rzoq55bk5/merge_from_jon-dev-test-merge.jpg))

**Note that Git merged the files by including BOTH identical functions (added in parallel) *'print_customer_part_order_history()'* - with no merge conflict**.  (This is the code snippet that Developer 1 added, in parallel, to the two branches.)  Therefore, this function appears twice in the merged code.

Note: the '*test-merge-sales*' branch has *the same whitespace* - leading spaces - in the highlighted code block in both branches.

Question 1: Why did Git decide there was no merge conflict?  Two blocks of code were added in parallel at the same location in the file.  Even though the blocks of code are identical, I would think that this should be a merge conflict.

---

**(2) Merge from '*jon-dev-test-merge-2*' into the '*test-merge-sales*' branch**

*Note: Due to comments below this question, the question associated with this merge scenario is already answered.*

[image: merge_from_jon-dev-test-merge-2.jpg]

(Click this [link to full-size image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t4q70vhs4nhuff8/merge_from_jon-dev-test-merge-2.jpg))

The only difference in the code being merged is that Developer 1 changed leading spaces to tabs.  **However, in this case, with only the whitespace difference, Git has declared there is a merge conflict**.

Question 2: Why - with only a difference in whitespace - would Git decide that in one case, there is no merge conflict, and in the other case, that there *is* a merge conflict?

---

My two questions are identified above, regarding how Git handles merges and merge conflicts.

Thanks!

---

**ADDENDUM**
I have added an additional screenshot - the relevant text of the file **BEFORE** the two branches diverged - along with descriptive text, in the section called "**(0) Base File**".  Thanks!

Comment: Short version: merge effectively runs two `git diff`s: base-vs-head1, base-vs-head2.  If the diffs match (with possible line offset changes) the merge is non-conflicting.  Whitespace changes don't match unless the diff is done with `-w`.  Merge allows `-X ignore-space-change` and similar options (see documentation) to control the `git diff` results.

Comment: As to the "why": git doesn't know what's in your files - maybe whitespace is important to the semantics of the file.  (For example, python.)

Comment: @torek - Thanks.  Regarding the *diffs matching*: I do not understand why the diffs, in the #1 merge shown above with the identical code block added in parallel on two branches (including whitespace), would successfully merge with the code block appearing twice in the merged file, rather than presenting a conflict.

Comment: That's the normal, desired behavior of a "three way" merge.  Given some transformation (add A, delete D, or change-Old-to-New), if the *same* transformation occurred base->head1 and base->head2, take one copy of it.  If only *one* transformation occurred, take one copy.  If two *different* transformations occurred, declare conflict.  (Note that there are some tweaks on this formula available, that's just the default behavior.)

Comment: @torek - The scenario (from your comment) `if the same transformation occurred base->head1 and base->head2, take one copy of it` seems to be exactly what occurred in the pre-merged files from "Merge #1" in the question - yet Git Merge took **two** copies of it.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Ah, that was very hard to see even in the enlarged text.  But it's *not* the *same* addition, because diff context matters: one adds four lines before the line with `load_web_services`, and one adds four lines before the `print_customer_part_order_history`.  Although the added text is the same, the surrounding context is different, so git has two different changes and applies both.  (This sort of thing is why you must always inspect the merge results.)

Comment: @torek - I would very much *like* to agree, as that is the obvious explanation, but it might not be correct. (If you click/download the image from *within* dropbox, it expands to its original size where it's easy to see, btw). I have added a **new screenshot** in my question to clarify (see the section titled **(0) BASE File**). To the base file, Branch 1 adds two functions, `print_customer_part_order_history` and `print_sales_analysis_page`. To the same location in its copy of the base file, Branch 2 adds just the first function.  Does this not count as 'same context'?  Thanks again!

Comment: (I have changed the title, and part of the body, to highlight the remaining unanswered question regarding the presence of TWO copies of identical code added to the same location in the base file in parallel, in the merged file.)

Comment: <Dude, who cares, GIT is beautifuuuul...> whine here :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty simple: when doing a `merge`, git analyze the lines that have changed on both size:

- If the changes are less than 2 lines apart<sup>(Reference is coming soon)</sup> this will create a conflict, since the changes are *very probably* about the same thing;
- If the changes are more than 2 lines apart the content from both side is considered as two different things and the content added **is not analyzed**, just added to the resulting file.

Since LHS added the function on `line 79` and RHS added it on `line 69` git thought that it was different content as it was more than a very few lines apart.

---

How to avoid this in the future?

- Proceed to a `diff` between the two branches, this will be visible if you read your diff carefully and then edit it in the merge;
- Communicate more within your team (if possible), is this normal that two developer wrote the *exact same* function in two separate branches?

---

From the [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) doc (emphasis is mine)

> HOW CONFLICTS ARE PRESENTED
>
> During a merge, the working tree files are updated to reflect the
>   result of the merge. Among the changes made **to the common ancestor’s
>   version, non-overlapping ones (that is, you changed an area of the
>   file while the other side left that area intact, or vice versa) are
>   incorporated in the final result verbatim**. When both sides made
>   changes to the same area, however, Git cannot randomly pick one side
>   over the other, and asks you to resolve it by leaving what both sides
>   did to that area.

Comment: Congrats to you and the OP! :)

Comment: ["Reference is coming soon"](https://www.memecreator.org/static/images/memes/4812866.jpg)