# How can I resolve a Duplicate identifier 'by' error?

Tags: angular, node-modules

I was doing some test using the `DomSanitizer` class. I undo all my changes using `git checkout -- .` and I got this console error:

I checkout into another git branch and the error is still there.

This are my specs

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.8
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.8
@angular/cli                      6.2.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.8
@schematics/angular               0.8.8
@schematics/update                0.8.8
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.16.4
```

This is the error

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/sanitization/security.d.ts(32,3): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'by'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.d.ts(83,31): error TS2720: Class 'DomSanitizer' incorrectly implements class 'Sanitizer'. Did you mean to extend 'Sanitizer' and inherit its members as a subclass?
  Property 'by' is missing in type 'DomSanitizer'.
```

I don't use `DomSanitizer` anywhere in my project, so I don't understand why I get this error when I run `ng serve`

This is what `node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.d.ts` contains:

```
export declare abstract class DomSanitizer implements Sanitizer {
```

My text editor was complaining about `implements` and I changed to `extends`.

I got a new error message:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/sanitization/security.d.ts(32,3): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'by'.
```

This is the content of `node_modules/@angular/core/src/sanitization/security.d.ts`

```
export declare abstract class Sanitizer {
  by: any;
  by: any;
    abstract sanitize(context: SecurityContext, value: {} | string | null): string | null;
}
```

It contains the `by: any` property twice, so I deleted one and it worked like a charm.

Can someone explain me why this happended? I don't understand why the content of a `node_modules` file could sudenly change.

Answer (score 0):

Node modules can be written (and released) by anyone. That means that the author of a module could update or take it down completely, whenever and without warning.

It's however very likely that this was git-related. See [Line Endings: Git merge creates duplicates without conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889915/line-endings-git-merge-creates-duplicates-without-conflict) for more on that.